# What do the numeric labels represent when extending themes in Chakra? (e.g 50:, 100:, 200:, etc)

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm following a Chakra/React tutorial and encountered the following:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    brand: {
      50: "#f0e4ff",
      100: "#cbb2ff",
      200: "#a480ff",
      300: "#7a4dff",
      400: "#641bfe",
      500: "#5a01e5",
      600: "#5200b3",
      700: "#430081",
      800: "#2d004f",
      900: "#14001f",
    },
  },
  fonts: {
    heading: `'Inter', sans-serif`,
    body: `'Inter', sans-serif`,
  },
});
```

See https://www.saasbase.dev/build-a-landing-page-using-chakra-ui/

What do the numeric labels represent?

Comment: Usually tone. For example, in TailwindCSS, `text-red-100` is lighter than `text-red-200`. Seems to be the case here as well since the colors get darker the greater the number.

Comment: What is the origin of using numbers (i.e. instead of descriptive labels)?  Is it based on the font weight system?  Are numbers used so that the values can be easily reversed for Dark Themes or something?  Why does it start at 50 (instead, say, from 100 to 1000 or 1 to 10)?

Comment: Numbers are easier to compare. For example, do you confidently know whether or not "really dark grey" is darker than "super dark grey"? Numbers are also easier to type. Numbers are numbers. There is only one way to write a number, but many ways to write words. It's simply more efficient. As for their scale, I don't know.

Comment: @caTS: Okay, but there's nothing to say that the colours in the palette are to be evenly spaced, numerically speaking... right?  The numbers may suggest even spacing when that isn't the case.  And I wasn't suggesting that the descriptive labels should be "really dark grey", etc.  But maybe, for example, "background-primary" and "background-secondary", etc.

Comment: Well again, because numbers are easily compared and their meaning and "distance" so to speak is always constant, it's just easier to use them over more descriptive tags like primary/secondary. Also, since you're using a library, it's easy to gauge how the number affects the tone or saturation of the color.

Answer (score 1):

The numeric labels are a color scale steps, each step can be used in a specific case, for your case:

| Step | Use Case |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | UI element background |
| 100 | Hovered UI element background |
| 200 | Active / Selected UI element background |
| 300 | Subtle borders and separators |
| 400 | UI element border and focus rings |
| 500 | Hovered UI element border |
| 600 | Solid backgrounds |
| 700 | Hovered solid backgrounds |
| 800 | Low-contrast text |
| 900 | High-contrast text |

this [page](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/colors/palette-composition/understanding-the-scale) from Radix UI Colors documentation has a good explanation of colors scale and when to use each one

Comment: You've helped me find more info online.  Including, it seems, that the origins of this system is from Google's Material Design.  I hadn't used Radix or Tailwind, etc. (after bootstrap I turned to vanila CSS).  I'd still like know a little more about why it's organized as it is (e.g. why does it start at 50 and end at 900 and why numbers and not descriptive labels).  Now that I know that the system is based on Material Design I feel like it'll be easier to find the answers to some of my questions.  Thanks.